# Google maps downloadUrl does not return 200

Tags: postgresql, google-maps

My code is based on the example of google code: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3
and was working fine.

I need to change a former 'gid' (Integer) field to 'id' (String) to get saved to the database and used to display a new labeled symbol on the map.

The strange thing is, that the url, that is build in the code to call the addrow.php file is OK. When I capture this string with alert(url), and I manually use this string, the new data is added to the database.

In my script, the call seems to fail (responseCode == 200 && data.length <=1), since no data is written to the database and the alert from the 'else-clause' is displayed as short pop-up.

Here's the code I use in my project (to save data from a form):

```
//save new marker to Postgis-database and add new markerwithlabel on the fly
function saveData(){
    var gender = escape(document.getElementById("gender").value);
    var hoehe = InZahl(document.getElementById("hoehe").value);
    var breite = InZahl(document.getElementById("breite").value);
    var id = escape(document.getElementById("id").value);
    var vital = document.getElementById("vital").value;
    var typ = document.getElementById("typ").value;
    var ein_mehr = document.getElementById("ein_mehr").value;
    var st_durchm = document.getElementById("st_durchm").value;
    var frucht = document.getElementById("frucht").value;
    var anmerk = document.getElementById("anmerk").value;
    var latlng = marker.getPosition();

    var url = "./mapdata/addrow.php?gender=" + gender +
        "&hoehe=" + hoehe + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng() +
        "&breite=" + breite + "&id=" + id + "&typ=" + typ + "&ein_mehr=" +ein_mehr + "&st_durchm=" + st_durchm +
        "&frucht=" + frucht +
        "&vital=" + vital +  "&anmerk=" + anmerk;  

    downloadUrl(url, function (data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <=1) {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setDraggable(false);
            marker.setIcon('./images/mm_purple.png');
            marker.labelContent = id;
            marker.setMap(map);

            downloadUrl("./mapdata/getxml_get_last.php", function (data1) {
            var xml = parseXml(data1);
            var ms = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("m");
            var gid = ms[0].getAttribute("gid");

            var html_n = "<div id='InfoWindow'><p style='font-weight:bold;'>" + id + "</p> \n\<p>Höhe:" + hoehe + " Breite: "+ breite + 
            "<br />\n\Typ: "+typ+" Stämme: "+ein_mehr+" St-Durchm: "+ st_durchm + "<br />\n\Vitalität: "+vital+" Fruchtbehang: "+frucht+
            "<p/>\n\<p style='text-align:right;'><a href='sm_juniperus.php?operation=ssearch&ResetFilter=0&SearchField=gid&FilterType=%3D&FilterText="+ gid + 
            "' target='_blank'> Daten editieren </a></p></div>";

            infowindow.setContent(html_n);
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html_n); 

            (function(i, marker, gid) {    
                var origIcon = marker.getIcon();
                new LongPress(marker, 1000);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'longpress', function(e) {
                    marker.setDraggable(true);
                    marker.setIcon(mmcross);
                });          
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
                    updatePosition(marker, gid);
                    marker.setIcon(origIcon);   
                });           
            })(i,marker,gid);

            //add new marker to markerCluster-Array and to markerArray
            markerCluster.addMarker(marker,false);
            markerArray.push(marker);
            i++;

            }); // End add new marker
        }
        else {
            alert("Your data couldn't be saved!"); 
        }         
    }); // End downloadUrl
}; // END saveData()
```

As I said, my code worked fine, but after 3 evenings passed to solve this, I thought it would be time to ask for help.
If anybody has an idea, where the mistake lies, I would apreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, you're aware that you by doing

`if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <=1) {`

you are saying 'if the request is successful and the data it returns is only one character or below in length'? I am unsure if this is intended or not, because this way the code inside the if statement is only ran if the response is successful but contains only 1 or 0 characters.

Comment: I admit, that since now, I did not think about the second condition `data.length <=1`. But the php-script to add data to the database does not return any string, unless an error occurs. So this would fulfill the condition above. I've tested the code without the second condition (only `esponseCode == 200`), but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Firebug tells me, that the  `downloadUrl (url, function (data, responseCode)` -call doesn't return 200 (and nothing is inserted in the database). Which is quite strange. When I insert the GET string in the browser manually, the data is inserted in the database?

Comment: The data won't be stored in the database since you explicitly called the database in the browser, not thru your script. What's the error code that was returned?

Comment: I don't get an error and I still don't understand what is wrong.. I use

Comment: Back again but still with no success. I've tried to reduce my code to the minimum (only the part with blank downloadUrl -call), but still I cannot add data to the database. When I use the string from the alert (url), the data is inserted??? It really drives me crazy since I use the similar function successfully on the same server.